# Why not directly connect to SQL servers from client? Why do we need application servers in client-server model?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, air, client-server

Many applications use the following model:

1. Browsers or other clients interact with application servers.
2. Application servers (web servers or RPC servers) interact with data store servers (SQL servers or non-SQL storage).

For internet applications, they need application servers because they must keep simple feature  on data servers for performance. But I can't see why they need application servers on **intranet**.

For example, can we develop an Adobe AIR application, which directly connect to a PostgreSQL server? I guess we can deploy a center PostgreSQL server which has many stored procedures and set strict permission, and let the Adobe AIR application fetch (and modify) data only by invoking the stored procedure.

Why don't the most of applications choose a simplier solution?

Comment: Your question is effectively "What is the advantages of multitier architechture?" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture et al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially started with a direct access design and quickly found it useful to move to an application server where I talked to the DB via web services. Reasons included:

- Handling DB restart, local connection loss, client IP address change, etc is much easier when you're talking to the DB over a stateless protocol like HTTP. This is more of an issue for remote workers.
- Transactions are clearly demarcated and isolated in server-side transactional methods (I used EJB3 and container managed transactions)
- It's much easier to add new clients like a phone app as they can share more of the code and business logic. Stored procedures in the database are very useful, but can be limited and occasionally frustrating.
- Some tools/languages don't have built-in tools for talking to PostgreSQL directly, but can easily talk to a RESTful web service with XML or JSON request/response format.
- DB admin is easier if you're dealing only with a single application server connection pool

The main downside is of course the extra layer means extra work and extra maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is no reason why you couldn't get an independent application to talk to a PostgreSQL server directly. Some applications do this and it works fine.

I'm not familiar enough with Adobe AIR to say whether it's possible in this context. In principle, if you can get a PostgreSQL driver, or if you can write your own using TCP sockets (the PostgreSQL [network protocol is documented in details in the official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/protocol.html)), you could certainly connect directly.

This being said, having a form of application server between the end-client and the database server isn't purely for performance.

Web-based development allows the SQL queries to be controlled by the server. Instead of exposing complete SQL access, you expose the features that the client can use. If you need to tweak the queries later (bug, change of data structure, ...), you can do this rather centrally on your application server, without having the need to deploy a new version of the client to each user.

Of course, you can do some abstraction like this user [server programming](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-programming.html) directly, but this isn't suitable for all applications. This may depend on what other features your application needs, for example if it needs to make use of a library programmed in another language. You can use some procedural languages bindings, but it's not always suitable: pl/Python is an "untrusted" language (which may cause security problems) and pl/Java needs a external add-on, for example.

In addition, not all applications are ultimately reserved for intranet usage nowadays. It often makes sense not to restrict yourself to intranet usage when you start designing an application.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but...

- Browser languages/libraries tend to have poor database support
- What happens when someone wants to use this application remotely?

If you're not talking about browser-based applications, then that is exactly what many do. There are plenty of traditional installed client applications talking to a backend database either directly or via a wrapper (odbc/jdbc).